# Will I be able to successfully run this Ubuntu (linux) setup in Virtualbox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, multiple-monitors

Have 4 DVI output. [Seems I hopefully will have driver support on this](http://reviews.cnet.com/graphics-cards/sapphire-radeon-hd-4850/4505-8902_7-33421567-2.html?tag=txt;page). Details are sketchy online about supporting 4 outputs, but seems possible.

My question is from the Linux group and Virtualbox pros.... Will the seamless method of VirtualBox allow me to use all 3 of my monitors for multiscreen. I'd like to stick with Ubuntu and run Visual C# and other tools from my VirtualBox. Compiz effects are just too amazing to want Aero Glass.

What do you think, will my system be able to use the multiple monitors with VirtualBox and this graphics card? I've googled for hours and am still searching for answers.

**Edit:**

I tried virtualbox last night. Pretty slick, though I had an error in installing Visual C#NET. However, it wouldn't let you drag between multiple screens??? Is this something the host must resolve, or does the guest session need to have special settings for multiple monitors? Haven't been able to find anything in google supporting multiple monitors with virtualbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to configure your screens just fine.  Don't know the exact details for an ATI setup, but you should be able to use [Xinerama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) to create a single large virtual desktop, and then just run VirtualBox (though honestly, I prefer [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine), which runs on modern CPUs which provide [native virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_virtualization) support) full-screen on one of those monitors.  You would then be able to have three screens dedicated to Ubuntu, and the forth dedicated to Windows.

You might want to look into the non-Xinerama method of multiple displays.  Each display is then treated as its own screen (so you'd have :0.0, :0.1, :0.2, and :0.3 for your X displays).  You cannot move applications between the screens, but you get four independent desktops.  I personally find that more useful than the idea of a single stretched desktop over multiple displays; when I used a laptop as my primary system, that's what I did, and when I get a second monitor for my computer, I'll likely return to that means of doing things.  You'll have to investigate the specifics for such a setup with ATI, but the X server supports it, so it's just a matter of looking at your ATI driver's documentation to put the pieces together.

Comment: GREAT quality answer. I'm new to Linux, but despite my first hatred (had problems with Nbdia)... I'm growing towards more and more. Faster, more secure, beautiful effects, free software. No need to pirate stuff. Stable longterm!

Comment: Absolutely.  :)  I've been using various Linux distributions since 1996, wouldn't ever look back.  By the way, if you're developing managed code, check out Mono 2.0 and MonoDevelop 2.0 Beta 1.

Comment: And of course you're developing managed code.  I somehow misread C# as C++.  *facepalm*.  Anyway, check that out, and you might even be able to write your software for both platforms!

Comment: that's great. I'm a student, so learning at this point. Classes require Visual Studio. My normal browsing and listen to music experince in Ubuntu has been great, but I have to use VS, therefore this seems like a great way for it to work. I just have to get my feet wet in more advance Linux cmds late